# Android Web server app generates HTML with saved images

Tags: android, html, webserver

I’m an Android newbie developer. This is my first post. I’ve hunted quite a bit for a possible answer to this and have not found anything that works. Basically, I’m saving an image file to /data/user/0/com.example.testing/files successfully. I need to create an HTML document that includes those image files. This is all happening in the same app. In fact, all the code is currently in the MainActivity class. I’m not interested in sharing the image with other apps, just want to have a very simple Web server that shows images. Any idea on how to store the images so that they can be output using my Web server? Thanks for any help you can provide.

code snippets

Saving code:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(localFileName, 0); // was Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("saveToInternalStorage() error", e.getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

Making HTML:

```
    sendMessage += "<img src=\"" + localFileName + "\"></br></br>";
```

HTML response Code:

```
try {
    httpServerSocket = new ServerSocket(HttpServerPORT);

    while(true){
        socket = httpServerSocket.accept();

        HttpResponseThread httpResponseThread =
                new HttpResponseThread(
                        socket,
                        sendMessage);
        httpResponseThread.start();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you storing those images there. So what is your actual problem? What is the question exactly?

Comment: Hi Greenapps. If I access the android Web server, I am unable to retrieve the images. Viewing the HTML source shows that syntactically it's correct but the Android is not providing the image. The server is running. I get the text part of the HTML code. It seems I don't know where to place the images so that they can be read externally. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The html source does not contain the images. It contains references to the images. Only names here. So the browser first gets the html and sees images mentioned in the html. After that the browser will request one by one those images from your server.

Comment: It looks as if you do not look which page or image it asks your server. I see no code where you determine what the browser requests. And i also do not see that you somewhere serve a jpg file. You have a lot to code yet. Now for every request you send that html.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, based on permissions, I can not have "world readable" files that can be accessed remotely, such as with a web browser. The final solution was to generate base64 encoded files and do something like:

```
<img src=data:image/jpg;base64,[lots of base64 decoded bytes]>
```

It's kind of messy and takes a lot of time to process. Especially if they are video files:

```
<video><source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,[lots of base64 bytes]"></video>
```

I'd like to know if there are more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: No this is a bad solution. Your webserver should serve the image files to. But you are not accounting for that.

Comment: `I can not have "world readable" files that can be accessed remotely, such as with a web browser. `. Nonsense. A browser does not access files on the device where the webserver is running. A browser on!y communicates with the webserver. And requests the webserver to send html or jpg files or whatever.